# `obj_addr` not returning expected output in .Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working through the [Names and Values](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#modify-in-place) Chapter of Hadley's Advance R book and am struggling with representing the 'modify in place' principal in my rendered RMarkdown file.

If I run the following in RStudio

```
library(lobstr)

v <- c(1, 2, 3)
obj_addr(v)
#> [1] "0x7fe6d48ff6f8"
v[[3]] <- 4
obj_addr(v)
#> [1] "0x7fe6d495cd78"
```

I get different `obj_addr` for `v`. I believe this is because

> "...the environment pane must make a reference to each object in order
>   to display information about it. This distorts your interactive
>   exploration but doesn’t affect code inside of functions, and so
>   doesn’t affect performance during data analysis. For experimentation,
>   I recommend either running R directly from the terminal, or using
>   RMarkdown"

When I run it in R directly I get the expected output.

```
library(lobstr)

v <- c(1, 2, 3)
obj_addr(v)
#> [1] "0x7f9bb683e138"
v[[3]] <- 4
obj_addr(v)
#> [1] "0x7f9bb683e138"
```

An object with a single binding that has been modified in place, and thus has the same object address.

However, when I render my .Rmd file to an html file, my output is the same as if I was running code interactively in RStudio. Why is this not consistent with Hadley's suggestion?

> I recommend either running R directly from the terminal, or using
>   RMarkdown

Comment: So what exactly does your Rmd file look like and how are you running it?

Comment: I'm running it using `rmarkdown::render()` and the only parameter I am using is `output:html_document`.